# Direct3D 12 Hello, World! sample issue. Window launches but no graphics

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, direct3d12

I am going through the following beginners tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/directx-graphics-samples/d3d12-hello-world-samples-win32

When I build, then run the project I get a window with the correct title of the project but it launches, then disappears after a second or so. It shows a blank, white window, no type of graphics or anything.

What do you think could be the issue? It's building and running without any errors so I am clueless. Screenshots are usually better than a 1,000 words so I included a screenshot of what I am seeing for each project I build and run. Any suggestions on how to get this to work properly?

I am running:
Window 10
OS Build: 19042.685
Version: 20H2

[Direct3D 12 sample program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x27u1.png)

Comment: Try running the latest [dxcapsviewer](https://github.com/microsoft/DxCapsViewer/releases) to check what hardware you have installed on your system that supports DX12. Also, make sure you have the 'Graphics Tools' Windows 10 Feature enabled.

Comment: *"What do you think could be the issue?"* - A question that a debugger is in a far better position to answer.

Comment: Thanks all for the replies back, I really do appreciate it! I have to admit, this is "over my head", it's like someone trying to compile/hack a linux kernel but doesn't even know how to use grep yet...haha...I think I'll learn/study/do C++, then come back to this at a later date. It's very interesting though and I hope to get to this level soon. I am especially interesting in C++ programming and graphics but need alot more of the basics first. Heh, I do not even know what a debugger does.  Thanks again!

Comment: Are you sure you have one of the samples that actually renders something selected as the startup project? Right click `D3D12HelloTriangle` in the Solution Explorer and select "Set as Startup Project"